# CSS alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I wander if someone could help.  I have developed a site for a client using Divs and CSS; that works beautifully in The latest versions of IE (IE8, and IE9). but it is being thrown out; i.e. the alignment is being thrown out  in IE7. I am not sure what is causing this issue and I really need someone's help on this. The url is www.exitretailsolutions.co.za

Comment: Please cut your code down to the minimum possible that exhibits the problem, and then ask a question about that.  It is not reasonable to expect someone here to wade through the entire HTML/CSS for a production web-page in multiple browsers.

Comment: First question, I know, but you're going to have to be a lot more verbose or specific to get any help. What have you already tried? can you pin it down to a few css statements that are causing the alignment issues? what have you done to rememdy? Do that, then post some problem code. Otherwise - its just a wide open, generic, and poorly framed question that noone can help with. cheers

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have to agree to the comments on your question, but I had a quick look at you CSS and may be found the cause.

You should avoid using `inline-block` for your `topsection` div and the form within that section. Use `display: block` and `position: absolute` for positioning rather than negative margins and `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Sorry I an mew to this forum and not entirely sure the best way to communicate my issues. I have basically tried the site using DIVS and CSS in thae latest versions of IE 8 and 9 as well as across Firefox, Chrome and Safari where the site seems to work perfectly. I am seeing a vertical and horizontal scrollbar in the center of the page as if the overflow for both x and y has been specified as auto. In addition certain elements are being thrown out which I feel may be due to a positional problem. I am not sure where to specify in the CSS where the problem may lie. for IE.7

Comment: As said in my answer do not use `display: inline-block`. Don't know how I can make this more concrete. Look at your stylesheet in line 11 and 12. `#topsection {` and `#hardsell {` have statements of inline-block.

Comment: yes I understand what you are saying. I will try that and see if there is positive outcome